# What is the Islamic view of the Law of Attraction?

Tags: belief, islamic-philosophy

Does Islam approve [Law of attraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_attraction)? I mean is it OK to think like that or it's conflicting with Islamic beliefs?

Is what they call "The Universe" same as Allah?

Is this in any way mentioned in Islamic resources?

Comment: can you tell me what is law of attraction?

Comment: @Abdullah very simple and short version: keep thinking about anything and it will happen to you.

Comment: Your link is to a Wikipedia disambiguation page.

Comment: @TRiG at the time I posted this question, the links was direct, but anyway, the idea came to me after watching [this film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_%282006_film%29) so you might wanna check for yourself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Personal belief)*

**1)** If you want to achieve or gain something in this way, actually you are invoking the universe to give it to you. And invoking/asking from anyone other than Allah is [shirk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirk_%28Islam%29). The following verses state about those who do this:

> وَمَنْ أَضَلُّ مِمَّن يَدْعُو مِن دُونِ اللَّهِ مَن لَّا يَسْتَجِيبُ لَهُ إِلَىٰ يَوْمِ الْقِيَامَةِ وَهُمْ عَن دُعَائِهِمْ غَافِلُونَ
>
> And who is more astray than he who invokes besides Allah those who will not respond to him until the Day of Resurrection, and they, of their invocation, are unaware.[[46:5]](http://quran.com/46/5)

-

> ذَٰلِكُم بِأَنَّهُ إِذَا دُعِيَ اللَّهُ وَحْدَهُ كَفَرْتُمْ ۖ وَإِن يُشْرَكْ بِهِ تُؤْمِنُوا ۚ فَالْحُكْمُ لِلَّهِ الْعَلِيِّ الْكَبِيرِ
>
> [They will be told], "That is because, when Allah was called upon alone, you disbelieved; but if others were associated with Him, you believed. So the judgement is with Allah , the Most High, the Grand." [[40:12]](http://quran.com/40/12)

-

> لَهُ دَعْوَةُ الْحَقِّ ۖ وَالَّذِينَ يَدْعُونَ مِن دُونِهِ لَا يَسْتَجِيبُونَ لَهُم بِشَيْءٍ إِلَّا كَبَاسِطِ كَفَّيْهِ إِلَى الْمَاءِ لِيَبْلُغَ فَاهُ وَمَا هُوَ بِبَالِغِهِ ۚ وَمَا دُعَاءُ الْكَافِرِينَ إِلَّا فِي ضَلَالٍ
>
> To Him [alone] is the supplication of truth. And those they call upon besides Him do not respond to them with a thing, except as one who stretches his hands toward water [from afar, calling it] to reach his mouth, but it will not reach it [thus]. And the supplication of the disbelievers is not but in error [i.e. futility]. [[13:14]](http://quran.com/13/14)

**2)** The universe is a creature of Allah and should not be supposed to do what just our creator, Allah, is able to do. Again it's called *shirk*:

> أَيُشْرِكُونَ مَا لَا يَخْلُقُ شَيْئًا وَهُمْ يُخْلَقُونَ
>
> Do they associate with Him those who create nothing and they are [themselves] created? [[7:191]](http://quran.com/7/191)

**3)** Allah has warned us not to be a Mushrik believer! So it's not that strange when you see some Muslims believe and obey this law of attraction:

> وَمَا يُؤْمِنُ أَكْثَرُهُم بِاللَّهِ إِلَّا وَهُم مُّشْرِكُونَ
>
> And most of them believe not in Allah except while they associate others with Him. [[12:106]](http://quran.com/12/106)

**4)** And as the last word, when Allah has promised to respond our invocations, **why not to call himself?**

> وَإِذَا سَأَلَكَ عِبَادِي عَنِّي فَإِنِّي قَرِيبٌ ۖ أُجِيبُ دَعْوَةَ الدَّاعِ إِذَا دَعَانِ ۖ فَلْيَسْتَجِيبُوا لِي وَلْيُؤْمِنُوا بِي لَعَلَّهُمْ يَرْشُدُونَ
>
> And when My servants ask you, [O Muhammad], concerning Me - indeed I am near. I respond to the invocation of the supplicant when he calls upon Me. So let them respond to Me [by obedience] and believe in Me that they may be [rightly] guided. [[2:186]](http://quran.com/2/186)

-

> وَقَالَ رَبُّكُمُ ادْعُونِي أَسْتَجِبْ لَكُمْ ۚ إِنَّ الَّذِينَ يَسْتَكْبِرُونَ عَنْ عِبَادَتِي سَيَدْخُلُونَ جَهَنَّمَ دَاخِرِينَ
>
> And your Lord says, "Call upon Me; I will respond to you." Indeed, those who disdain My worship will enter Hell [rendered] contemptible.[[40:60]](http://quran.com/40/60)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I know that I can't ask "the universe" for anything as a Muslim, I was thinking what if they just mean god when they talk about "the universe" and I wonder how would it be like if we switched this "universe" with god and see if it is acceptable by Islam.

Comment: @Farzad Bekran - Even if they are doing so, they're simply ignoring the God and replacing the most greatest existence with one of its creature. And why should we switch the universe with God in this so-called _law of attraction_ then see what happens. We do have Dua in our religion. It gives us whatever this law is supposed to give and even more

Comment: true I think I'm convinced to ignore this way of thinking and stick to the Islamic ways. but some nice teachings exist in this law that I will try to remember.

Comment: @Farzad Bekran - I think it's the right path. Scince I watched their movie I've always tried to perform their teachings in an Islamic way, such as calling the God continuously and repeatedly and believing that all the good is in his hands and I can have whatever I want

Answer (score 5):

I have always felt that the law of attraction is compatible with Islamic teachings.
We ask Allah SWT for things everyday through duas and prayer (somewhat like the "positive thinking" in the law of attraction).   This being said, one of the stated reasons for unanswered duas (and what I believe to be the main culprit when my duas aren't answered) is when the worshipper thinks that dua will not be answered (in advance).   To me it's like a lack of confidence and trust in Allah SWT — this resembles somewhat what the new-age folks believe with respect the "law of attraction".

Not thinking positively of God may have invocations unanswered.  There are a number of relevant ahadith from the prophet Muhammad, such as the following:

> "**Make du'a to God in a state that you are certain that your du'a will be responded to, and know that God does not respond to a du'a that originates from a negligent, inattentive heart**"
> <sup>—narrated by al-Tirmidhi and al-Hakim from Abu-Hurayrah and authenticated by al-Albani in sahih al-Jami</sup>
>
> "**Allah, may He be exalted, says: ‘I am as My slave thinks I am.’**"
> <sup>—Narrated by [al-Bukhari, 7405](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/97/34); Muslim, 4675</sup>

I don't think what you were thinking was shirk; you were just looking for another way to understand or view teachings which already existed.  I personally gained a better understanding of how important my faith in Allah's will, generosity, guidance, love (unconditional despite my human imperfections) and mercy is after reading about the law of attraction and reflecting on the Islamic teachings.

In my case, I think I lacked faith that Allah SWT would answer my duas because I wasn't a good enough person.  I now know that such a belief is, in a way, equivalent to shirk because I am basing it on my own perceived human limitation — who am I to interpret how our Lord will view me, especially when he has made his mercy abundantly clear to us?  I just need to have faith, blind faith in Allah SWT.

I would also recommend reading the following blog post, which I believe sums it up best:  http://muslim-mind.com/2011/05/optimism-and-the-law-of-attraction-in-islam/

Does this make sense?  Was this kind of along the lines of what you were thinking?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Shia Islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam) most of its laws are compatible with Islam but still some critiques remain according to Islam. They are useful but at their situation and not for every purpose. These laws are very idealistic, for example if one think to remaining young does not prevent aging and death. Best case of these laws in Islam are [Dua](http://duas.org/).

These laws discourage action and recommend only thinking. For example Iran Islamic Revolution never happened with only thinking. Thinking is recommended in Islam but not "Only thinking". For example a man came to mosque and left his camel at door of mosque. Prophet SAWW said him: why you did not fasten it? He said: I trusted on God! (I.e. God will protect my camel for me). Prophet SAWW said: fasten it and trust on God! But in law of attraction being worried for car to be stolen is clearly rejected.

In Islam too much thinking to worldly goals is discouraged and instead thinking to hereafter is encouraged. And gaining world for Islamic goals and not as independent goal is recommended. (Working and living to gain more world (wealth,..) is considered worshiping world and is same as idol worshiping and is Shirk) but gaining world for serving family and satisfying God is in fact worshiping Allah.

[Here](http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/20716) is a full answer to this question based on Quran verses and hadith by analyzing the [The Secret (2006 film)](http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/20716) and comparing it with Islam teachings by an expert team of Shia Islam scholars. The answer is in Persian language and long and needs time to translate. InshaAllah I translate a summary of it and improve this answer.

> The Secret (2006 film) is a film based on the law of attraction. It
>   was then developed into a book of the same title in 2007. The movie
>   and book gained widespread attention in the media also from Saturday
>   Night Live to The Oprah Winfrey Show in the United States. Ref:
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_attraction

---

**References:**

- [www.pasokhgoo.ir](http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/20716)

Answer (score 2):

The idea about the universe encompasses us, is the same as the idea that Allah SWT encompasses us and be close to us as closest the jugular veins (2:115, 50:16).
It's just names. (12:40)
And for Allah SWT the names of every beautiful names (7:180)
And if we asked, Allah SWT will answer (40:60)
So in the spirit of finding commonalities (3:64), I would tend to the notion that Islam is compatible with the ideas of the secret. And the secret is Al-Kitab.

One of the ideas behind the last supper is exactly the grant that Allah SWT gave to humanity, and the disbelievers would say that Allah SWT does not grant such privilege; but the prophet 3eesa proved them wrong by providing the last supper sent from Allah SWT.

Wallahua3lam

Answer (score 1):

Lets take evolution as an example, whether it is true or not is not a concern to you if you believe in God because at the end of the day you know that what ever is 'evolving' it is through The Power and Will of God, and NOT things evolving themselves and creating themselves ( this is an atheist's point of view). We all agree on that.

On the same token, when we use the 'law of attraction', it is God providing us through His Will and law which he has put in the universe and NOT the universe ITSELF providing us. If I do believe that IT IS the universe answering my calls and the universe which is providing me - that is where their is a problem.

In conclusion, the 'law of attraction' DOES NOT refute or accept God/Allah it is our belief system on which we see it through and operate with it through which determines that. At the end of the day it is just a law, just like the law of gravity, the laws of physics etc.

The Prophet peace and blessings be upon him illustrates this concept beautifully in a portion of an authentic hadith in Sahih Muslim:

> 'Do you know what your Lord has said?' They replied, 'Allah and His Messenger know best.' He said, 'This morning My slaves have become divided up into believers and unbelievers. Those who said, "We had rain by the favor and mercy of Allah," believe in Me and reject the stars. Those who said that it was because of a certain star, disbelieve in Me and believe in the stars."'"

Answer (score 1):

What "The Secret" has done is put a secular spin, with some shirk, on an already prescribed form of prayer in monotheistic faiths. For example, in Islam, Muslims may ask Allah SWT for a halal wish. The way to do this is: a) believe in Allah SWT, b) ask Him in prayer of your halal desire, c) believe that He hears your supplication and that He will help you (maybe not in a way that we expect it, because after all He knows what is good for us) and d) be grateful regardless of the outcome. Visualization may be a way to reinforce one's desire for something as well as to make strong our belief that the prayer will be answered. However, a Muslim knows, that no matter whether we are aware of prayers being answered or not, we know that we still must be grateful. 
"The Secret" took the same concept of praying to God/Allah SWT, and switched it around into shirk: 
a) it is asking that people believe in "universe," telling people that the "universe" is people's servant and the people are the "true" masters (this OPPOSES Islamic teaching and instruction!)
b) it is asking that people make a clear request (stolen concept from the monotheistic teaching)
c) visualize that you have it and pay attention to opportunities (maybe something new, not part of a religious tradition, but with a lot of scientific support--e.g. positive thinking affects mood, helps people be more grateful about their life and circumstances, confident, etc.)
d) be grateful and not force the outcome--because you can't (stolen from the monotheistic teaching)

Belief in the One--Allah SWT who has created everything is the most important. "The Secret" contradicts itself: it tells people that they are "gods" yet it also instructs them to "pray to the super powerful universe." At the same time, according to "the Secret," this "super powerful universe" is incapable of knowing real from unreal, positive from negative, etc.

I have been always using Islamic method of making supplication--but must admit that visualization interests me, and I think it can help strengthen my belief in Allah's SWT guidance, help and my gratefulness for His help and everything He has done for me as His creation.

Answer (score 0):

The example the link give me reminds me of a verse form the quran:

> 2:117- The Initiator of the heavens and the earth: to have anything done, He simply says to it, "Be," and it is.

I do not believe this power is granted to humans, who are less than their creator.

As well as this, the example given seems a lot like what is known as [Reporting Bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reporting_bias). You only remember when what you expect to happen happens.

Comment: true but they say that it's the universe that responds,that's the way it works. now i'm asking could this universe be actually Allah? and if there is anything to approve or disapprove this in Islam?

Comment: If your asking is Allah the universe then no, Allah is seated upon his throne, i.e. islam does not claim Allah is omnipresent. If you are asking if what they call the 'universe' is actually Allah then...I'm going to say no but it's not as clear cut. I don't think anyone calling on the 'universe' consciously or subconsciously would 'get' Allah, unless they intended to call on him.

Comment: this is the verse that actually made me think there might be some Islamic evidence behind all this: http://quran.com/40/60 very close to what they claim if you think what they call "universe" is actually Allah but they just dont know it.

Comment: I've just asked a question on this as I think that will help me answer it insha Allah.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better to distinguish between Allah and his traditions (i.e. Allah's Way of dealing with some behavior: سنت الله). The traditions He has approved are just some rules that He has put to this universe:

> … وَلَن تَجِدَ لِسُنَّةِ اللَّهِ تَبْدِيلًا
>
> … No change wilt thou find in the practice (approved) of Allah.
>   (Al-Ahzab:62)

if you see someone ill and get afraid of that then the same disease will catch you as well, rather we should say thanks to Allah for the health that he has provided for me, instead of being afraid saying I hope I'll never get ill with such a disease. Also there is another tradition that says: "کما تدین تدان" which implies in any way that I deal with others the others I will be treated with the same behavior sometimes before my death. Or it is stated that no one taunts of a wrongdoer unless he WILL do the very same sin before his death. And among these traditions (*many of them described by Ahlol-Beyt in their Ahadith*) is what you mentioned:

> And your Lord says: "Call on Me; I will answer your (Prayer)
>   (Al-Ghafir:60)

And

> And be ye not like those who forgot Allah; and He made them forget
>   their own souls! Such are the rebellious transgressors! (Al-Hashr:19)

If I am right. To be precise If I am right "Low of attraction" is more or less accepted in Islam, but only as a rule (a tradition) of Allah not Allah Himself, Allah is not the universe (passive) but He is the creator and describes Himself as active (contrary  to passive in the scientific language).

Godspeed

Comment: this brings up another question: could this law exist as a tradition of Allah?

Comment: About that you said "_law of attraction = (roughly) keep thinking about anything and it will happen to you_", it depends, maybe this verse can help you: "**To any that desires the tilth of the Hereafter, We give increase in his tilth, and to any that desires the tilth of this world, We grant somewhat thereof, but he has no share or lot in the Hereafter.**" (Ash-Shura:20) That desiring I guess is what you meant by "keep thinking about".

Comment: However I just don't see the relation between "Law Of Attraction" and asking either from Allah or universe, you may use the rules of Allah for your benefit,we have many Ahadith from AhlolBeyt AS encouraging this and even showing its ways. How to gain more blessing in our aliments during business, how to live longer, and etc. A famous example of increasing the length of life is by paying for charity.Is that shirk that you pay for charity to increase your life length when you know the effect is from Allah and not the money?No!But if you think the money itself has such an effect it would be shirk

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuh.

A main point is that Muslims who claim the law of attraction is Islamic actually change the interpretation and meaning of the law of attraction so that it becomes Islamic (asking Allah for help etc.).
In other words, they change the law of attraction into something Islamic and then say the law of attraction is Islamic.

However, the Secret is, actually, not Islamic and not about asking Allah for help at all! It's totally unIslamic, shirk and kufr as the top answerer wrote! It's about asking the universe to help you.

It also uses lots of lies: the universe doesn't simply respond to you by giving you parking spots. You don't get to control the universe using some 'superpower'! Rather it is Allah who controls the universe!

It is kufr and shirk. It only becomes Islamic when you change the whole concept. But the real 'law of attraction' isn't Islamic at all!

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of people Confusing law of Attraction with the ALLAH SWT. Allah is the creator and  rest of all his Creation (Makhlook) except Quran which is Kalaam of Allah SWT.

The Law of Attraction Works the way , Allah  SWT has honored his will to his creation to some extent and to that extent creation can perform the act of creator. For example Allah has created us , Allah Says that i listen to you, I watch you, i respond you... Don't you see that Allah has given us the Power to listen , To Watch, to Respond. But the listen of a human and listen of the Allah SWT can not be Same, we can listen to the extent we have been given the Power , we can see to the extent we have been given the Power to see... and Its the Allah who gives the Power to every thing under his Active Control... So to the UNIVERSE , if you See the word UNIVERSE means TOWARDS ONENESS and oneness only Belongs to Allah SWT, who has given powers to the Universal Laws and Truths which are existing from the Start of the Time under the will of Allah....

So LAW OF ATTRACTION IS NOT AGAINST ISLAMIC BELIEVES, TILL WE BELIEVE THAT THIS LAW IS A WILL OF ALLAH SWT, AN AMMR OF ALLAH SWT...

AND ALLAH SAYS IN SURA-E-YASEEN... when he Wishes for something to happen, HE JUST SAYS, BE AND IT HAPPENS

ALLAH O AKBAR ... EVERY THING ELSE IS UNDER HIS CONTROL WITH SOME GIVEN AUTHORITIES

Answer (score 0):

I see all of the above posts which are absulotly true   but they did not mention the law of attraction which is proved from the Holy Quran and The Hadith.
At the biggining  i am also confused when i read the law of attraction so i did research on it because i am not want to shirk with Allah due to i am muslim so i did reseach on it.I meet with my muslim freind who learn the islamic skills at Madrarssa of Akorrra Khatak, I says to my freind about the Law of attraction and i tell him plz tell me "is it right or not in the islam". He tell me in the anwer a long story which was told him by his islamic teacher during the class time.

I am not writting the whole story here because the whole story is too long i am just writting a little bit from that.
Before explaing the  story i am informing you about the story.
It was the story of "Mulana Ashraf Thanvi R.A ".

In the story there was a magician (Sahir or jadooger) who challenged  The Mulana Ashraf Thanvi (R.A) to find his secret work which he will doing before him.
One day Mulana Ashraf Thanvi(R.A) and his friends going there and meet with that magician that was the challenge day which was taken by them.

The magician tell them that he will not doing the magic before them,
he will just doing some secret work and The Mulana Ashraf Thanvi (R.A) will find it.

Before starting the secret work he tell them that he will just look to the chair  only for 15 minutes  the chair which was present before them and after 15 minutes
he will back and forth the chair just looking to it.
So the magician started his secret work .He just look to the chair for 15 minutes and after that he back and forth the chair ,when he done his work after that he ask the Mulana Ashraf Thanvi(R.A) to tell him how he do this? "is it magic or something else if something else what is it". When the Molana Ashraf Thanvi (R.A) realized he said that this was not the magic but he did not know the secret behind the magician work, so he did not brick the challenge and he say to him that he will soon find out this secret.

When Molana Ashraf Thanvi(R.A) and his friends  going come out from there. Mulana Ashraf Thanvi(R.A) ask from Allah for that secret work and Allah said to him ,when someone keep in mind and want to do something and just focus on it and have strong belief that it will happened so it's happened.Because this is the power of mind which was created by Allah.

I mentioned here some links it will give you more understanding and it is also proved from the Holy Quran and Hadith  just watch these videos it will helped you.

watch this Law of attraction in islam
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dhg7snvf_wY

Answer (score 0):

The word universe signifies a system that works on autopilot that you are in. It could be like saying that you are in oness with all of creation and open to recieve. Therefore saying that a system is working for you aka the universe is not shirk. However always ask Allah ffor things you want.

Answer (score -1):

Law of attraction states that a positive attitude and positive thinking attracts goodness in your life. We ought to worship Allah alone. The law does not require u to worship anything else. It simply gives u way to pray in a manner by which your wishes get fulfilled. Whenever u have a desire, ask Allah for it and believe with a strong conviction that He will answer your prayer. Have blind faith in His Supremacy and InshAllah your prayers shall be answered no need to think that you are controlling your destiny or the universe is answering your call. Just believe in Allah and that's a point of view. Rest Allah knows best!

Answer (score -1):

God has made subservient to you whatever is on the earth or in universe. You are destined to rule over the Universe." - Quran

What’s this verse of the Quran speaking about??? Simply this verse is speaking about the human ability, this verse is simply talking about the Form of law of attraction, not only this, there r tons of verses in the Quran which speaks about law of attraction, and according to me Quran is the best book on planet to understand the law of attraction. 
So if ppl says tht universe is like a God than?? And even Quran also says that call Allah by any name but it should be most beautiful name..

So if any one who blvs tht universe is like a God, or God is like a universe thy r correct... But, the problem with humans are, we know that God exist but still we always try to deny somehow. I’m asking question why followers of law of atraction has problem to directly ask to God.. ?? Because of our bad deeds and intentions to the world or may be ppl tht we afraid of God somehow.. But Allah is not our the best of best friend.. We do not need to afraid.. So instead of asking to universe it is better to ask to God..

Or if you still not convince.. Than i would like to tell you this-

O man God has bestowed on you excellent faculties and has created life and death to put you to test in order to see whose actions are good and who has deviated from the right path." - Quran

So always remember that we r on test, it means God has created this universal power which is work on our command, so when we ask anything to universe it will give you.. Because it is created by Allah(God)  so if you want to menifest anything, universe will give you.. But never ever forget that this powers of universe is created by God, so you shall thanks to God for creating this powers wich works on your command and then you can thanks to this universal powers also after God.. This will be correct and perfect.. Thanking to God is very important..

As the prophet Muhammed(pbuh) said- gratitude for the abundance is the best insurance that abundance will continue..

It means prophet knows the law of attraction.. And according to me there is no one better than prophet who knows the law of attraction perfectly..

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE, and thank you for your nice contribution. But a few points to improve your answer quality: please avoid casual abbreviations in writing answers; be clear and concise; provide supporting references for your answers. Also go through [guidelines on answering](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

The question here is whether in the so called "Law of Attraction" what they call as "The Universe" is actually Allah? And just they dont know it? My answer is surely NO. Its not that Universe is Allah, because Universe is just one creation of Allah, and as you know what we call universe is only one of many components of the "Multiverse" and Allah is the creator, maintainer and protector of every single micro inner component in it. We already know that the sky, the planets, the space, the sun and the moon all are just the obedient desciples of Allah just like the Malaakat. So is the universe, who is answerable to Allah.
Who except Allah and His messenger knows the best that if the so called law of attraction is something in which the creator has planned certain things to function? Even if it is so, It is still a Shirk to ask one of His creations or chose any shortcut to get something when the Creator Himself has promised that " Ask mse and I will give". This definitely falls in to Shirk and on the day of reckoning, will surely be asked up on.